# Remove HTML text on scroll

Tags: html, scroll

I am trying to remove an element (`<p>`) from my HTML code as soon as the user scrolls down, and after the first scroll, it will not come back until a reload occurs. I couldn't find anything here, or on Google on this, so help would be appetited.

HTML

```
<body>
    <div id="scrolltext">
        <p>I go missing when the user scrolls, never to return</p>
    </div>
</body>
```

I don't really know where to go from here, I think JavaScript would be needed, or at least a CSS scroll property of some sort.

I will add it in here that I am ok with using a combo of HTML CSS and JS.

Comment: Do you want to remove an <p> on scrolling from DOM without returning the given <p> in the current session?

Comment: HTML and CSS cannot achieve dynamic DOM manipulation related to scrolling.  
JavaScript can.

Comment: @s.kuznetsov I have heard the term DOM before, but not quite sure what it means (Other than it stands for Document Object Model.)  I just want the tag to be removed immediately after the scroll bar moves, and have it never returned to the page until it is reloaded. Hope that clarifies.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use method `remove()`to remove any item from DOM  inside window `onscroll` event.

Tag `<p>` will be removed after the first scroll, and will only appear again after reloading the page.

```js
let p_remove = document.querySelector("#scrolltext p");

window.onscroll = function () {
    p_remove.remove();
};
```

```css
body {
    height: 5000px;
}
```

```html
<body>
    <div id="scrolltext">
        <p>I go missing when the user scrolls, never to return</p>
    </div>
</body>
```

Comment: Not me, I actually like your answer the best, it is in code that I can understand, and has the least of it. Thanks!

Comment: @Greenreader9 Well, you should take into account that this answer came 7 minutes later than the first one with the same principle - but teaches you bad practices (almost like w3schools) - regarding `let` instead of `const` and the sloppy use of `on*` handlers (instead of the proper `addEventListener`). Also it does not detach the listener from the element (done by `removeEventListener`). So many bad things I'm also thinking about downvoting.

Comment: @RokoC.Buljan It will still work with all browsers though, right? I want code that I can understand so when that I go back into it later (When I forget to use comments) I understand what it means. Is there a snippet (About that removeEventListener thing) that I could add to make it better or more 'correct'?

Comment: @RokoC.Buljan, I don’t understand what bad example you’re talking about. My example answers the OP's question pretty well. `let` and `const` work the **same**, except that you **cannot override** `const`. That's the whole difference. And why should I fundamentally use an **remove event listener** for such a simple example ?! This is my solution, and I myself will choose how I do it!

Comment: @RokoC.Buljan, And it is possible that deleting tag `<p>` will not be the only logic in its project at event scroll. Therefore, I did not apply event listeners, as well as `removeEventListener` and `addEventListener`.

Comment: @Greenreader9, Yes, don't worry. This code will work well.

Comment: @s.kuznetsov your comments make no sense. Perhaps from a lack of understanding how listeners work. You should know by hearth that you should never use `on*` handlers - well, unless you're creating a brand new Element from in-memory.

Comment: @Greenreader9 it will fail if some plugin out of your control already assigned an `onscroll` handler to `window`. Basically by using the code provided here you're killing that plugin (or even some other file of yours) that uses that same eventName. I cannot stress more that people should never use `on*` handlers. Just giving you an advice. Also, a scroll event is really computationally expensive, and the suggestion to terminate that event is far a better and superior solution.

Comment: @Greenreader9 here's an example of the potential issue: https://jsfiddle.net/kw0r78em/ (Open Dev Tools console (F12) to see the logs)

Answer (score 0):

HTML and CSS cannot achieve dynamic DOM manipulation related to scrolling.
JavaScript can.

```js
// Get (and cache) the desired Element from the DOM
const EL_scrolltext = document.querySelector("#scrolltext");

// Function to remove the element,
// and remove the expensive scroll listener
const removeScrollText = () => {
  EL_scrolltext.remove();  // Remove element from DOM
  window.removeEventListener("scroll", hideScrollText);
};

// Remove the Element once the user scrolls
window.addEventListener("scroll", removeScrollText);
```

```css
body { min-height: 300vh; }
```

```html
<div id="scrolltext">
  <p>I go missing when the user scrolls, never to return</p>
</div>
```

Be aware that the above will not be triggered if the page cannot be scrolled (has no scrollbars)

Read more:

- [MDN: querySelector](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelector)
- [MDN:  addEventListener](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener)
- [MDN:  removeEventListener](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/removeEventListener)
- [MDN:  Scroll Event](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/scroll_event)
- [MDN:  Element Remove](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/remove)

Comment: Thanks for all the additional info you added at the end, it might be helpful later down the coding road!